# Spring Security UI plug-in can't find CSS resources

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails 2.4.2 and trying to use Spring Security UI (1.0-RC2). There some issue in trying to find the resources used by the plug-in as I get the error:

- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
- Module [spring-security-ui] depends on resource [/assets/reset.css] but the file cannot be found

The file can be found at //static/css/reset.css. Why is the wrong URI being generated for this resource? How is this location determined?

Comment: You may look to the plugin sources, maybe your issue is a bug. Look, that version still in RC